# Java convert String text to base36 and from base36 to hex

Tags: java, encoding, hex, decoding, base36

Is there any api in java to convert simple string to base36/base10 and from base36/base10 to hex representation.

example: `input: '-22EEVX' encoding base36`
output: `f8  8d  33  23`

Comment: There is no such thing as 'base36 in hex'. Do you mean *from* base36 *to* hex?

Comment: Yes @EJP, I'm looking for string to base36 and then base36 to hex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Integer` class and radix parameter of [`parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)), and `toHexString` from the same class.

```
Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt("-22EEVX", 36));
```

For base10 it is even shorter (you omit radix parameter, it is assumed `10`):

```
Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt("-22"));
```

Comment: Thanks, @krzyk but it's giving error for `Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt("-22EEVX"))` as java.lang.NumberFormatException:

Comment: @subodh Because you used version with base10 to parse base36 string. Use the first code fragment with `36`

Comment: Thanks a ton for this simplest way, if i need back to actual string is there anyway such as above or do I need to convert byte byte?

Comment: do you have any idea how to get the actual string from the above one?

Comment: What do you mean string from above one? You get a string from `toHexString`

Comment: Exactly, I am getting encoded string from `toHexString` but now if I want original string(`-22EEVX`), I mean decoded than how to do that.

Answer (score -2):

It may be useful to you If you want any string to encode and decode in base36.To use it in base 10 replace all 36 in below code to 10.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Base36 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = convertHexToBase36(toHex("8978675cyrhrtgdxfawW#$#$@$#"));
    System.out.println(str);
    String back = convertBase36ToHex(str);
    System.out.println(fromHex(back));

}

public static String fromHex(String hex) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2) {
        String str = hex.substring(i, i + 2);
        output.append((char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
    }
    return output.toString();
}

public static String convertHexToBase36(String hex) {
    BigInteger big = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(big.toString(36));
    return sb.reverse().toString();
}

public static String convertBase36ToHex(String b36) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(b36);
    BigInteger base = new BigInteger(sb.reverse().toString(), 36);
    return base.toString(16);
}

public static String toHex(String arg) {
    return String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes()));
}
}
```